# Android Back/Up Navigation using nested Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

We are adding a loading dialog as a fragment as a temporary view within a container to show the user while data from the server is processed before showing the main view. We want to be able to show this dialog inside a panel such as a frame layout because the particular view we are using is a custom container fragment to emulate the iOS SplitViewController. Potentially, when loaded on a tablet, there could be 2 of these loading fragments showing at the same time in their respective containers.

The fragment we are using inherits from DialogFragment and all the other fragments are basically heavily customised list fragments.

The problem we are facing is, when we add the temporary fragment to the container directly using the Fragment's childFragmentManager.Replace() method, it completely messes up the back navigation. When it is used as a modal dialog calling dialog.show() the back navigation is fine, but the dialog doesn't show in the frame we want it to.

Is there a way to either a.) fix the back nav problem or b.)make the dialog show in the specified frame when calling dialog.Show()?

Here is the code for the dialog fragment:

```
public class TestLoadingFragment : DialogFragment
{
    public override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
        this.Cancelable = false;
        this.HasOptionsMenu = false;
        this.SetStyle(StyleNoTitle, 0);
    }

    public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.TestLoadingFragment_Layout, container, false);

    }
```

`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="200dip"
    android:minHeight="200dip">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/loadingViewProgress"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Loading Please Wait"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblViewLoadingText"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/loadingViewProgress"
            android:textColor="#ff000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>`

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ListFragment` you can call `setListShown(false)` to show a loading progress indicator while loading the data, and when the listview is ready call `setListShown(true)`.

Or if you want a customized spinner layout view, you can declare a `<ListView>` item and a `<LinearLayout>` inside a `<FrameLayout>`:

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:visibility="visible" 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:minWidth="200dip" 
        android:minHeight="200dip"> 
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
            <ProgressBar 
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/loadingViewProgress" 
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" /> 
             <TextView 
                android:text="Loading Please Wait" 
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/lblViewLoadingText" 
                android:gravity="center" 
                android:layout_below="@+id/loadingViewProgress" 
                android:textColor="#ff000000" /> 
        </RelativeLayout> 
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And set only one view visible at a time:

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
LinearLayout spinner = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

When loading data:

```
spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

When data is ready:

```
spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response! We tried SetListShown() and unfortunately it throws a Java Exception saying we can't use that method with custom content view. I think it's because in the list view we have added a view above the listView content a drop down for filter views (My, Recent, Favorites etc.) and a TextView for searching.